# Spring Inheritance, Many to Many, Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inheritance, many-to-many

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owQ6Z.png)

Hi,  I'm trying to map many to many relationship between two classes Employee and Manager extending from the Class Person. The problem is that both classes have the same id since they extend from the same super class. That's why I get the exception

```
... Repeated column in mapping for entity ...
```

Could please help to solve this problem by keeping the inheritance design.

Note : The generated Class from the relashionship have extra attributes.

**Java Classes**

**Person**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="discriminator",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="P")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    protected int personId;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_FIRST_NAME")
    protected String personFirstName;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_LAST_NAME")
    protected String personLastName;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_EMAIL")
    protected String personEmail;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_IMAGE")
    protected String personImage;

    // Constructors and Getter/Setter methods,
    public Person() {
    }

    /**
     * @param personId
     * @param personFirstName
     * @param personLastName
     * @param personEmail
     * @param personImage
     */
    public Person(String personFirstName, String personLastName, String personEmail, String personImage) {
        this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
        this.personLastName = personLastName;
        this.personEmail = personEmail;
        this.personImage = personImage;
    }

    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return personFirstName;
    }

    public void setPersonFirstName(String personFirstName) {
        this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
    }

    public String getPersonLastName() {
        return personLastName;
    }

    public void setPersonLastName(String personLastName) {
        this.personLastName = personLastName;
    }

    public String getPersonEmail() {
        return personEmail;
    }

    public void setPersonEmail(String personEmail) {
        this.personEmail = personEmail;
    }

    public String getPersonImage() {
        return personImage;
    }

    public void setPersonImage(String personImage) {
        this.personImage = personImage;
    }

}
```

**Manager**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("M")
public class Manager extends Person implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="Budget")
    private double budget;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="manager",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Meeting> listAppointment;

    public Manager() {
        super();
    }


    public Manager(String personFirstName, String personLastName, String personEmail, String personImage, double budget) {
        super(personFirstName, personLastName, personEmail, personImage);
        this.budget=budget;
    }

    public double getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }


    public void setBudget(double budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    //meeting
    public List<Meeting> getListAppointment() {
        if (listAppointment == null)
            listAppointment = new ArrayList<>();
        return listAppointment;
    }

    public Iterator<Meeting> getIteratorAppointment() {
        if (listAppointment == null)
            listAppointment = new ArrayList<>();
        return listAppointment.iterator();
    }


    public void setListAppointment(List<Meeting> newListAppointment) {
        removeAllAppointment();
        for (Iterator<Meeting> iter = newListAppointment.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
            addAppointment(iter.next());
    }

    public void addAppointment(Meeting newAppointment) {
        if (newAppointment == null)
            return;
        if (this.listAppointment == null)
            this.listAppointment = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!this.listAppointment.contains(newAppointment)) {
            this.listAppointment.add(newAppointment);
            newAppointment.setDoctor(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeAppointment(Meeting oldAppointment) {
        if (oldAppointment == null)
            return;
        if (this.listAppointment != null && this.listAppointment.contains(oldAppointment)) {
            this.listAppointment.remove(oldAppointment);
            oldAppointment.setDoctor(null);
        }
    }

    public void removeAllAppointment() {
        if (listAppointment != null) {
            Meeting oldAppointment;
            for (Iterator<Meeting> iter = getIteratorAppointment(); iter.hasNext();) {
                oldAppointment = iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                oldAppointment.setDoctor(null);
            }
        }
    }
    // End Meeting

}
```

**Employee**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {


    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employee",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Meeting> listAppointment;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(String personFirstName, String personLastName, String personEmail, String personImage) {
        this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
        this.personLastName = personLastName;
        this.personEmail = personEmail;
        this.personImage = personImage;
    }

}
```

**Meeting.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEETING")
public class Meeting implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "MEETING_ID")
private long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") 
private Manager manager;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")  
private Employee employee;

// additional fields
private boolean activated;
private Date registeredDate;

public Meeting() {
}

public Meeting(Manager manager, Employee employee) {
    this.manager = manager;
    this.employee = employee;
    this.id= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(manager.getPersonId()).concat(String.valueOf(employee.getPersonId())));
}
```

**Java Exception**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.gestion.GestionCliniqueApplication.main(GestionCliniqueApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.gestion.modele.Meeting column: person_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:835) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:875) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:607) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you show your `Meeting.java` entity?

Answer (score 1):

**Fisrst**,I think you should change the InheritanceType for class Person

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

**Second**,Add id for class Employee and Manager.

Comment: I did, but I'm still getting the same problem, since both subclasses inherit the same id. and in Metting class, I should be the join fo two different classes with different ids.
Class : Metting 
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") 
 private Manager manager;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")  
    private Employee employee;

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem, by adding :

```
targetEntity= Manager.class
```

and removing:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
```

See the code below :

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MEETING")
    public class Meeting implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "MEETING_ID")
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity= Manager.class)
        private Manager manager;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Employee.class)
        private Employee employee; 

        // additional fields
        private boolean activated;
        private Date registeredDate;

        public Meeting() {
        }

        public Meeting(Manager manager, Employee employee) {
            this.manager = manager;
            this.employee = employee;
            this.id= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(manager.getPersonId()).concat(String.valueOf(employee.getPersonId())));
        }


        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


        public Manager getDoctor() {
            return manager;
        }

        public void setDoctor(Manager manager) {
            this.manager = manager;
        }


        public Employee getClient() {
            return employee;
        }

        public void setClient(Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
        }

        public boolean isActivated() {
            return activated;
        }

        public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
            this.activated = activated;
        }

        @Column(name = "REGISTERED_DATE")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        public Date getRegisteredDate() {
            return registeredDate;
        }

        public void setRegisteredDate(Date registeredDate) {
            this.registeredDate = registeredDate;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the column(s) mapping name. For example, from:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") 
private Manager manager;
```

With something like:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_AS_MNGR_ID") 
private Manager manager;
```

HTH

Comment: Changing the JoinColumn to PERSON_AS_MNGR_ID will cause java.lang.NullPointerException: null, since it doen't exist. The Id of both classes id Person_Id

Comment: I've reproduce your entities here: https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/tree/so-50438729 . It is works as it should be. Unless you have another part of code that not posted here, your NullPointerException problem is doesn't make sense at all. As far as I know, NPE never thrown in mapping problem.

Comment: Hi, 
Sorry fir the delay, this solution does not work for me as expected, I'm having :

..... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null